# Equivalence testing: options and alternatives in real life

Tags: hypothesis-testing, equivalence

I have read several posts about equivalence testing, I can also see that there are many questions about it on CV... but I feel this type of tests might be tricky, especially for people like me with little statistician background. To reduce the scope of my question, let's assume that I am interested in sample comparison where a traditional t-test can apply (continuous data from a simple random sample, etc.).

Apparently, when we are talking about equivalence testing, the standard approach seems to be [the following](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/535387/321901) (which seems less obvious to manipulate). Then I read about [TOST](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/500121/321901) which seems very similar actually to the previous method.

I have seen also that people are talking about variance test and define an acceptable value for variance/standard deviation that will prove that the sample are similar. I guess confidence intervals might also be used to interpret equivalence...

So, what are the options when we want to test equivalence?

Comment: Compare your parameter of interest. [Here is an example on my former blog](https://stla.github.io/stlapblog/posts/EquivalenceExceedanceProbabilities.html), where I do an equivalence test for exceedance probabilities.

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneLaurent, seems very interesting! I need to dive into it now...